# Regular Expression to replace & in URL

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Due to some error our website is having links to urls with & in the url. For example /movies-&-plays/find/. However this throws a 404 resulting in a lot of broken links on webmasters, since this is not handle in our application. 
Is there a way to replace the '&' to 'and' in these type of urls, i.e. only those urls with /find/. This is so that a regular expression can be written to write a 301 redirect to all such kind of URLs to the url with 'and' instead of &. For example /movies-&-plays/find/ must be redirected to /movies-and-plays/find/. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can match ampersand with `\&`, so a substitution might look like `s/\&/and/g` in whatever dialect you want to use...

Comment: @MaximDsouza can't there be multiple `&`?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/(\/[^\/ &]*)&(?=[^\/ ]*?\/find\/)/$1and/g' FILENAME
```

When given this input:

```
http//www.web.com/hello&goodbye/find/

///////&/junk/to/test
////&/find/
```

the following output is produced:

```
http//www.web.com/helloandgoodbye/find/

///////&/junk/to/test
////and/find/
```

Answer (score 0):

For URLs matching `([^&]+&[^&]*)+/find/`  replace all `&` with `and`.

Comment: This is not a full solution.  Without showing what needs to be captured and how the replacement is to be done, you restated the question.  Sorry.  I wasn't trying to be petty.  I should have written an explanation of my downvote. :)

Comment: @protist OP hasn't stated the language used. In java replacement can be done without capture group in this case. There is a `replaceAll` function for doing this. As long as the language is not stated as perl the answer can't be downvoted i think.

Comment: @protist In php, `preg_replace` replaces all occurrence of patterns matching given regex, in the input. There also `preg_replace ('/&/', 'and', $subject, -1, 0)` will do the job ($subject stands for input). Here also capture group is not significant.

Comment: Ah, very interesting! :)  I will revert my downvote.  Can you show me what the whole preg_replace would look like?

Comment: @protist Why should I edit the post? The question is not language specific. So I asked to find the matching URLs and do the corresponding replace function.

Comment: I said "It will not let me revert my vote until you edit the post.", not "I will not revert my vote until you edit the post.".  I was saying that "I /cannot/ revert my vote until you edit the post because StackOverflow will not let me.".

Comment: `You last voted on this answer
55 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited`

Comment: There is, however, a flaw in your regex.  Because you did not exclude spaces and `/`s from your character class, your regex could change `texttextext&text web.com/differentpart&/this&that/find` into `texttextandtext web.com/differentpartand/thisandthat/find`.

Comment: I suppose you said `For URLS matching` but even if you are only working with URLs and not text you could change the wrong fields of the URL.